# Is there a way to clear the to visit queue in crawler4j during crawling

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am trying to figure out a way to change seed at crawling runtime and delete completely the "to visit" database/queue.

In particular, I would like to remove all the current urls in the queue and add a new seed. Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

private int discarded = 0;

@Override
public boolean shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url) {
    boolean isDiscarded = checkPage(referringPage,url);
    if(isDiscarded){
        this.discarded++;
        if(discarded >= 100){
            //Clear all the urls that need to be visited
            ?_____?
            //Add the new seed
            this.myController.addSeed("http://new_seed.com");
            discarded = 0;
        }
    }
    return isDiscarded;
}

....
```

I know I can call controller.shutdown() and start everything again but it's kind of slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** build-in functionality for achieving this without **modifying** the original source-code (via forking it or using Reflection API).

Every `WebCrawler` obtains new URLs via a `Frontier` instance, which stores the current (discovered and not yet fetched) URLs for all web-crawlers. Sadly, this variable has `private` access in `WebCrawler`.

If you want to remove all **current** URLs, you need to reset the `Frontier` object. Without implementing a custom `Frontier` (see the  [source code](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/frontier/Frontier.java)), which offers this functionality, resetting will not be possible.